# Alter column Datatype

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `dbo.ExceptionMessage` and now I want to change the column datatype `nvarchar(100)` to `nvarchar(MAX)`. I used alter query for changing this

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ExceptionMessage ALTER COLUMN   Address nvarchar(MAX)
```

and while excecuting this query it shows some error like.

> The object 'DF_ExceptionMessage_Address' is dependent on column 'Address'.
>
> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Address failed because one or more objects access this column.

How can we solve this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change column datatype in SQL Server database without losing data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136013/how-to-change-column-datatype-in-sql-server-database-without-losing-data)

Comment: That dupe doesn't appear to help here. OP is already using the sql in the answer from that question, the key was he needed to drop the dependent constraints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First Delete all Constraint Like this

```
ALTER TABLE TableName DROP CONSTRAINT [DF__TableName__ColumnName__FieldName]
```

and then perform change

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ExceptionMessage ALTER COLUMN   Address nvarchar(MAX)
```

then re enter the constraints

Comment: If you **DROP** a constraint - you should also **RE-APPLY** it after you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find out which type of constraint DF_ExceptionMessage_Address is, drop it, alter the column type and then re-create the constraint if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

you try first:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> DROP CONSTRAINT <Con_Name>;
```

And Then Do your Alter

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ExceptionMessage ALTER COLUMN   Address nvarchar(MAX)
```

Again Add Constraint

Answer (score 0):

thiz help you to alter

```
   alter table TableName 

     alter column ColumnName nvarchar(200);
```