# How to replace a string in stored procedure in sql server through query

Tags: sql-server

I have a procedure with following code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE customer_panel_insert(
    @Panel_Name VARCHAR(200),
    @Panel_description VARCHAR(5000),
    @Type_of_change  CHAR(5)) 
AS
   DECLARE @data_set VARCHAR(MAX);
   DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);

   begin
      set @sql = 'select * from customer_details where panel_type = 1 AND PANEL_DATATYPE = ''VARCHAR'''

      exec @sql 
   END
```

I want to change the `varchar` datatype to `nvarchar` and `char` to `nchar`. Change the `varchar` variable with size more than 4000 characters to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. I want to change with help of a query.

Is there any query that can replace

Comment: Replace String is different. What you are asking is how to change the datatype of a column in a table through query.

Comment: That is not the requirement. i want to change the procedures contents with nvarchar in place of varchar

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change column datatype in SQL Server database without losing data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136013/how-to-change-column-datatype-in-sql-server-database-without-losing-data)

Comment: Hi chandan, The change is to happen in the contents of stored procedure

Comment: Generate a alter script for the SP and do a quick replace [Ctrl+F] of all VARCHAR(MAX). Is it what you want to do?

Comment: So you're asking how to alter the stored procedure itself?

Comment: i have a thousands of stored procedures in the database where i have to change all varchar to nvarchar and char to nchar in stored procedures only. i need to loop through the sys.procedures and replace the datatypes with help of query

Comment: Please mention your last comment as an update to your main question. This is exactly what makes your question unique!

Comment: no change of schema is required but the procedure contents should be modified

Answer (score -1):

Hope this works for you. **Be careful before executing it**.

```
update sys.sql_modules set definition = REPLACE(definition,'VARCHAR(5000)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
where definition like '%VARCHAR(5000)%'
```

Comment: what about changing VARCHAR(5000) to NVARCHAR(MAX) . i have around 11000 stored procedures , shall i have to do one by one

Comment: i have some variables whose length is between 4000 to 5000 characters . As nvarchar supports 4000 characters as constant size

Comment: Hello Sir, we want to convert the same through scripts as it is not possible to generate  scripts for 11000 stored procedures through SSMS generate script option and it involves a lot of manual work to do so for the procedures