# how to fix this please

Tags: sql, mariadb

I Created the db with phpmyadmin and created 8 columns i forgot to create date column i tried to create it with this code and i got this

```sql
ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "cdate" DATE
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '"users" ADD "cdate" DATE' at line 1

Comment: Table and column names should be enclosed with backticks not double quotes.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE users ADD cdate DATE` delete the double quotes

Comment: If you really want to use that syntax (which is not the default) you'd need to [enable ANSI_QUOTES](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql-mode/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change column datatype in SQL database without losing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136013/how-to-change-column-datatype-in-sql-database-without-losing-data)

Answer (score 1):

You can Use phpmyadmin to add a new column without any code

Or Use this :

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `cdate` DATE
```

> You should use this ` not this "

Answer (score 0):

you can add columns to existing table using phpmyadmin
below the table structure you can find add [num] columns

and since you asked

```sql
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `cdate` DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about this in the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name column_definition
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need any qoute

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD cdate DATE
```

Backticks are to be used for table and column identifiers, but are only necessary when the identifier is a [reserve word of mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

Comment: thanks it worked but it is put by default with php my admin